# FEM for a biphasic drying problem

Tags: finite-element, method-of-lines, coordinate-transform, axisymmetric

I have the following PDE originating from a biphasic drying model, where $\xi \in [0,\Xi]$ is a radial coordinate attached to the dry skeleton of a wet cylindrical body:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{\xi}\frac{\partial}{\partial\xi}\left(\xi D_\xi \frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}\right), \quad D_\xi = \frac{D}{(1+\alpha u)^2} \left(\frac{r}{\xi}\right)^2
$$
The scalar $u = u(\xi,t) = \rho_\textrm{l}(r,t)/\rho_\textrm{s}(r,t)$ is the moisture content on a dry basis, defined as the ratio of volumetric concentration of liquid and solid, $D$ is an effective diffusivity, $\alpha$ is a shrinkage factor, and $r = r(u(\xi),\xi)$, $r \in [0,R(t)]$, is the radial position corresponding to $\xi$ in the wet reference frame (i.e. the Eulerian or geometric reference frame). At $t = 0$ we assume a homogeneous moisture distribution $u(\xi,0) = u_0$.

At $\xi = r = 0$, the moisture distribution is symmetric:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi} = 0.
$$
At the surface $\xi = \Xi$ (or $r = R(t)$) either a Dirichlet or Robin condition is prescribed depending on the magnitude of the Biot number. Both are captured by the equation:
$$
-\rho_\textrm{s}^* D_\xi \frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi} = k_Y(Y^*(u) - Y_\textrm{air}).
$$
When ventilation in the dryer is strong, the Biot number, $\textit{Bi} = k_Y R(t)/D$ will approach infinity, leaving the equilibrium relation $Y^*(u) = Y_\textrm{air}$ which can be solved for $u|_\Xi = u^*$. The function $Y^*$ is a constitutive equation also known as the [moisture sorption isotherm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moisture_sorption_isotherm).

The relation between $r$ and $\xi$ is found from the mass balance of solid over a differential element (an annulus),
$$
dm_\textrm{s} = \textrm{constant} \quad\longrightarrow\quad \rho_\textrm{s} (2\pi r) dr = \rho_{\textrm{s}}^* (2\pi \xi)d\xi,
$$
where $\rho_\textrm{s}$ is the concentration of solids, and $\rho_\textrm{s}^*$ is the partial density of pure solids. In an ideally-shrinking biphasic system, the two quantities are related by a constitutive equation:
$$
\frac{\rho_\textrm{s}}{\rho_\textrm{s}^*} = \frac{1}{1 + \alpha u}
$$

By taking the integral over the differential element, we can find the wet radius:
$$
r^2 = \xi^2 + 2\alpha\int_0^\xi u(\xi') \xi' d\xi' \longrightarrow \left(\frac{r}{\xi}\right)^2 = 1 + \alpha \frac{2}{\xi^2} \int_0^\xi u(\xi') \xi' d\xi'
$$

To solve the model I'd like to use the *method of lines* in combination with a **finite-element** discretization of the governing equation. It appears like at each time step I need to compute the cumulative integral of the moisture content to obtain the values $r(\xi)$. (For example the MATLAB [`cumtrapz`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumtrapz.html) function could be used for this purpose.)

Alternatively, taking the derivative of $r$ with respect to time, and the fact that $\partial \xi /\partial t = 0$, we can do the following manipulation:
$$
2r\frac{\partial r}{\partial t} = 2\alpha \int_0^\xi \frac{\partial u(\xi',t)}{\partial t}\xi'd\xi' = 2\alpha \xi D_\xi \frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi},
$$
giving,
$$
\frac{\partial r}{\partial t} = \alpha \frac{\xi}{r} D_\xi \frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}.
$$
This equation gives the trajectories of $r(\xi,t)$ and lends itself to discretization using the method of lines as an additional set of ODEs for the position of the finite element edges. With a $C^0$ FEM basis however, the derivative $\partial_\xi u$ is discontinuous between elements, hence it would appear this method is not applicable.

**What options do I have to circumvent this problem and which of them would you recommend?**

My current list of options is:

- Use the integral relation and forget about $\partial r/\partial t$
- Use an $L_2$-projection of the derivative $\partial_\xi u$ onto the original $C^0$ basis
- Use a $C^1$ basis, where the derivatives at the edges are continuous
- Use FDM or FVM instead

Any other thoughts will be also appreciated.

For better imagination of what the solutions tend to look like (here shown for a constant Dirichlet boundary condition $u^* = 0.1$, and initial concentration $u_0 = 0.3$):

[image]

Note the movement of the surface in the bottom right corner.

Comment: In your first equation, what is x?

Comment: It was a typo. Sorry about that.

Comment: I don't see any reason why either of your two proposed approaches
won't work. It is not uncommon in FEM for spatial derivatives of a
dependent variable to be discontinuous at the element nodes; this is
one of the strengths of FEM. You typically need to compute these
derivatives only at interior points in an element.

Comment: Can you include the boundary and initial conditions for your problem?

Comment: I've added the BC's. Are you implying I only need to evaluate $r$ at the quadrature points, so the edge values are not needed? While I tend to solve for $u$ as a function of $\xi$, for plotting it's convenient to know the $r$ values at the cell edges.

Comment: With FDM, all variables live at the nodes, so the method of lines tends to work as expected. With FEM however, I'm confused where should I place $\partial_t r$, $r(\xi,t)$ and $\partial_\xi u$.

Comment: To evaluate the FEM integrals, all the derivatives are evaluated at the
quadrature points. For plotting purposes, it is common to evaluate
the derivatives at the quadrature points, extrapolate those values
to the element nodes, and then simply average the values between
adjacent elements.

Comment: I have been experimenting with your equations. Can you give me typical values for $D$ and $\alpha$?  Thanks.

Comment: Sure: $\alpha = 1.5$ and $D = 1 \times 10^{-9}$ m^2/s. The initial wet radius $R(t=0) = 0.001$ m, corresponding to a dry radius $\Xi = 0.00083$ m. This should roughly correspond to a strand of spaghetti.

Comment: Here is a Python script reproducing the graph above using the approach with the integral relation: https://gist.github.com/ivan-pi/216498e9321af416d99870de1077cd68

Comment: In my comment with the parameters, the diffusivity should be 1.E-10 instead. This gives a drying time of approximately 100 min.

Answer (score 1):

I solved your equations using the `pdepe` function in MATLAB and your
second approach. That is, I included the second PDE that describes the
evolution of $r$ with time. This two-PDE approach is more straightforward to implement with `pdepe`. The `pdepe` function basically uses a low-order finite
element approximation. As I said previously, I believe the choice between your two approaches is mostly due to computational convenience.

This analysis produces the figure below that is comparable to yours.

[image]

Below is the MATLAB script for this problem.

```
function cse_10_26_2023_pdepe
m = 1;
nx=100; 
r0=1e-3;
Xi=0.00083;
xi = linspace(0,Xi,nx);
t=[0 30 60 120 240 480 960 1600 3200 6400];
nt=length(t);
D=1e-10;
alpha=1.5;
u0=.3;

pdef=@(x,t,u,DuDx) pdefun(x,t,u,DuDx,D,alpha);
bcf=@(xl,ul,xr,ur,t) bcfun(xl,ul,xr,ur,t);
icf=@(xi) icfun(xi,u0,Xi,r0);

opts=odeset('abstol', 1e-12);
sol = pdepe(m,pdef,icf,bcf,xi,t,opts);
u=sol(:,:,1);
r=sol(:,:,2);

figure; hold on;
for i=1:nt
  plot(r(i,:), u(i,:));
end
hold off;
title 'u at different times';
axis([0 r0 .1 .35]);
timeLabels=arrayfun(@num2str, round(t), 'UniformOutput', 0);
legend(timeLabels);
xlabel 'r';

figure; plot(xi, r(end,:)); title 'r at final time';
figure; plot(t, u(:,1)); title 'u at center as a function of time';
figure; plot(t, r(:,end)); title 'r at outer surface as a function of time';
disp(r(:,end)');
end

function [c,f,s] = pdefun(xi,t,U,DUDxi,D,alpha)
u=U(1); r=U(2);
DuDxi=DUDxi(1);
Dxi=dxi(D, alpha, xi, r, u);
c = [1 1]';
f = [Dxi*DuDxi 0]';
s = [0 alpha*xi/r*Dxi*DuDxi]';
end

function U0 = icfun(xi,u0,Xi,r0)
U0=[u0 xi/Xi*r0]';
end

function [pl,ql,pr,qr] = bcfun(rCenter,uCenter,rOuter,uOuter,t)
pl = [0 uCenter(2)]';
ql = [1 0]';
pr = [uOuter(1)-.1 0]';
qr = [0 1]';
end

function Dxi=dxi(D, alpha, xi, r, u)
Dxi=D/(1+alpha*u)^2*(r/xi)^2;
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful demonstration. The pdepe routine uses a Petrov-Galerkin method when the domain includes the singular point $r = 0$. Your boundary functions for the right side sets $f(\Xi,t,u,\partial_\xi u) = 0$ (zero-flux), however `f = 0` from `pdefun`. This strikes me as slightly odd, even though "do nothing" is precisely what I'd want for $r$ at that boundary. Is setting `qr = 1; pr = 0` always granted to give behavior consistent with a natural boundary condition?

Comment: Yes, setting the BC that way is simply a trick to satisfy pdepe requirements.

Comment: My full problem also has a coupled ODE (a lumped energy equation for the temperature), but it appears like `pdepe` can't be used in this case. Would the `pde1dm` solver work in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a lumped energy equation but pde1dm does allow for coupled ODE. A common use for this is to account for a non-standard BC. If you run into problems, post a mathematical description of your equations along with your matlab code.